# Redis occupies more memory

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-server

**OS:** RHEL 7.6

**Cluster set up:**

Single node - 6 instances of redis - 3 master and 3 slaves.
16384 slots shared between three masters.

**Sample data:**

```
smembers 201904138
1) "0"
2) "1"
3) "2"
4) "3"
5) "4"
```

Each set contains 5 ids. I have such 2.49Million keys.

**Sample size occupied by each entry:**

```
memory usage 201904138
(integer) 76
:7001> memory usage 201904132
(integer) 76
:7001> memory usage 201904134
(integer) 76
:7001> dbsize
(integer) 2489174
```

So logically it should occupy `2.49M * 76 = 189MB`. I do understand that it stores some extra information as well.

But total memory occupied by this cluster is `Memory = 367M, RSS=389M`

Why it is double than the original data? how can i reduce it?

Please help.

Comment: What does the `info memory` command print out? Redis is not very good at releasing memory once it grabs it. So, it may be that the instances once had more memory than before and just never released it.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Thanks. Info also shows same 367MB.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Is it because of replication?